# How to prevent non-root load of a LaunchDaemon

Tags: launchd, plist, daemons

I want to prevent a LaunchDaemon (/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycorp.service.plist) from being loaded by a non-root user.

Running `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycorp.service.plist` starts the service. Running `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycorp.service.plist` without sudo will load the service, but because my service exits immediately when not run as root, it doesn't actually do anything other than reload repeatedly.

Is there a way to prevent a non-root user from running `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycorp.service.plist`? The following do not work:

- chmod 600 com.mycorp.service.plist (not readable to non-root)
- chmod 000 com.mycorp.service.plist (not readable to any user!)
- Using the UserName key in com.mycorp.service.plist - apparently this is ignored when launchctl is not run as root

With the above changes, launchctl load still works (uselessly) as non-root.

Comment: Not a full solution, but: how about having the service program check its UID, and if it's not 0 throw up a notification or something similar (to the user it *is* running as) that it hasn't been loaded properly & how to fix it (`launchctl unload ...` as user, then `sudo launchctl load ...`). Or you might even be able to fire of the process of reloading in a semi-automated fashion, but that might be tricky.